# Use one state to assign multiple different values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component where I define a state that creates an object with different values inside it.
In this component I'm mapping a child component six times and I'm passing the state in props.
Inside this child component, I have multiple dropdowns that modify the value of the state.
The problem is that when I change the value of a dropdown it affects the values of the other dropdowns.
[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-hamilton-8n2y6d?file=/src/App.js) where I recreate the problem.
I tried adding [i] at the end of the value but when I clear the fields it throws an error saying that pokemon.name is null even though it works for the moves.
Should I declare more states (one for each mapped component) or is what I'm trying to do possible ?

Comment: declare pokemon as array instead that containes 6 objects and then do `pokemon[i].name`

Comment: @Alen.Toma And how do I do when I use the setPokemon to modify the for pokemon[i] because I tried doing setPokemon[i] but it doesn't work ?